# How to get USSD request value in Android application?

Tags: android, ussd

I want to make an application where I want to dial USSD request using GUI in android and get the value of pop up windows in my application and interact USSD dialing using GUI. How can I do this?

Comment: I searched in google and Android developer also but there is no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no conclusive answer for USSD API in Android. This is because they are attaching security concerns with it. In fact, they recommend using other alternatives such as web services.

Comment: This should be comment i think